# Query on Android detecting chop twice using accelerometer

Tags: android, flashlight, shake, chop

How to write code for detecting chop twice shake in android using accelerometer. In Motorola latest devices, found this feature. On twice shake flash light will be shown. Please help. Gone through many forums for accelerometer code. But almost every snippet of code is detecting slight movement of device also as one shake or chop.